# weird jsp output - Application working under eclipse, but not directly under tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat

J2ee application (Spring 4.0, jsp ,java 1.7 e) is working great in the dev env (eclipse with built in tomcat)

Once deployed onto tomcat outside eclipse - it will render Gibberish output (class names, file names , configuration file names some binary data)

I didn't find any exception in the logs, according to the debug logs - like the request was processed correctly on the controller side.

I went over the jar packaged in the WAR and it seems like the list is identical to the list in build configuration in eclipse

Any idea what could cause this?

Sample source output:
[weird jsp output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uus1D.png)

EDIT

After some more research I Found three missing jars (eclipse vs deployed version)

```
javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar
junit-4.11.jar
hamcrest-core-1.3.jar
```

I found this jar packaged in the war:

```
jsp-api-2.2.1-b03.jar
```

Should this jar be in the war?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are deploying it in standalone tomcat, proper directory structure has to followed. http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/appdev/deployment.html Another important thing is the mapping of your servlets in web.xml 
Hope this helps you. Thanks

Comment: Issue was corrupted JSP, but I will accept your answer, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Issue was corrupted JSP files 

What corrupted my JSPs is still a mystery.